# has done or did when using "during"?

Tags: tense, past-tense

Which one is correct:

- During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) **has also visited** Venice.
- During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) **visited** Venice.

Thank you.

Comment: If you could let us know what you've done to try to figure this out, or research to look it up, that might help us know what you're unclear about. Also, if they're a couple it's still plural, so it would be **have also visited** (at least in the dialect I grew up with - that might be varied between dialects).

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct grammatically.

The difference is that one is the simple past, while the other is present perfect. The simple perfect conveys the sense that something happening in the more distant past and is completed. The present perfect can only be used if the thing being discussed is still continuing. So, depending on you context, they may not both make sense.

> I met a couple today. They told me that during their trip they have also visited Venice. [The trip is still happening.]
>
> Back in December I met a couple. They told me that during their trip they also visited Venice. [The trip is over.]

Answer (score 0):

Both could be correct, although in different circumstances, whether or not you'd introduced the wholly unhelpful "( a guy and a girl)"

Please accept that grammatically, it makes no difference whether the couple was your guy and a girl, or two guys or two girls.

It's true that such a Question hardly ever arises but when it does, the gender of the people makes no grammatical difference: a couple can be a man and a women, or a couple of men or a couple of women; their gender matters not.

Dropping both "( a guy and a girl)" and the equally irrelevant “During the same trip” should leave us with a straight comparison:

“…the couple has also visited Venice.”

“…the couple visited Venice."

If those are the choices then “During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) has also visited Venice…” will never be correct.

Similarly, “During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) visited Venice…” will always be accepted.

I’m sure you won’t welcome this comment, yet I suggest you made that Question far too complicated for your own appreciation of English.

If you doubt that, please re-consider how your own chosen title, ‘has done or did when using “during” ‘ matches the content of your Question.

I suggest there is no match: has done or did when using “during” is simply not supported by your examples:

```
 During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) has also visited Venice.

 During the same trip, the couple ( a guy and a girl) visited Venice.
```

Broadly, my suggestion is that you drop any Questions back at least one level of English. Would that hurt?